# How to hide top toolstrip bar in ajax html editor extender

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a asp.net textbox with ajax html ajax htmleditor extender in by deafault all toolbars will come if we write tollbars tag inside htmleditor extender by using this we can show the toolbars what ever we want but i want to hide entire toolbars. please help me

Comment: Read this document:[http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxcontroltoolkitsamplesite/htmleditorextender/htmleditorextender.aspx]
This document contains following information:
Toolbar - This provides facility to customize toolbar as per requirement. This tag is optional and if user does not provide toolbar tag then by default all buttons will be populated in the toolbar. User must add at least 1 button in the toolbar tag.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the following link showing how to hide some of the buttons with wrapper of it. You can use it for hiding all or displaying some of them. 
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/ajax-control-toolkit/htmleditor/how-do-i-use-the-html-editor-control-cs

Answer (score 0):

http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxcontroltoolkitsamplesite/htmleditorextender/htmleditorextender.aspx

Dont use the title property for

```
     <ajaxToolkit: /> within toolbar <Toolbar>
```

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Use the css or jquery

```
.ajax__html_editor_extender_buttoncontainer { display : none !important }
```

- See more at: http://www.dotnetlines.com/forum/tabid/86/forumid/6/threadid/142/scope/posts/Default.aspx